# Basic authentication in Github api with http request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, github

I'm trying to use basic authentication in [Github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication). I wrote something like this:

```
require 'httpclient'

request = HTTPClient.new
request.set_basic_auth("http://api.github.com/authorizations", "my_username", "my_password")
request.get "http://api.github.com/user/repos"
```

and expect it returns the repos of a user. However, it keeps throwing an error:

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "api.github.com" port 80 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I know there are a whole bunch of gems like `github`, `octokit` that do the stuff for users. I want to try it myself. Does anyone know how do I authenticate with a simple http request in Ruby?

Comment: Side note, consider using Peter Murach's [GitHub gem](http://peter-murach.github.io/github/) or another wrapper. Also doubles as the single best use of unicorns and rainbows in web design yet discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an HTTPS request instead of HTTP.  Authentication always needs to use SSL.

You are also using the wrong URL's.  As per their docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication) you need to set your basic authentication to the following path:

```
https://api.github.com/user
```

And make your repo request at:

```
"https://api.github.com/users/<USERNAME>/repos"
```

So your request would look something like

```
request = HTTPClient.new
request.set_basic_auth("https://api.github.com/user", "my_username", "my_password")
request.get "https://api.github.com/users/<USERNAME>/repos"
```

I suggest taking a look at the documentation that I linked to above, and make your first attempt by using curl requests, as they offer more information to help you debug.

Comment: Thanks I changed them to `https` but I still got a message in json, saying that `{"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}` Is  my method in sending the request correct?

Comment: Adler I just updated my answer.  All of the URL's you are using are wrong.